# How to pause and buffer Observables in RxJS v5

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-streams

I'm trying to implement a backpressure strategy on HTTP requests, to temporarily hold back pending requests for a number of seconds under certain conditions.  The logic to pause will be based on another Observable.

My research and understanding leads me to believe the `pausableBuffered` operator does exactly what I need.  Documented here http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html.

However I can not find this operator in ReactiveX v5 (5.0.0-beta.0) and the migration guide (v4 - v5) seems to indicate they have been dropped.  If this is the case, how can I achieve the desired result with the v5 available operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backpressure story has been [dropped](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/71) entirely for now.

Here's one way to get the same result:

```
const pausableBuffered = (observable, pauser) => {
    const subj = new rx.Subject();

    let buffer = [];
    const nextEmitter = x => subj.next(x);
    const nextBuffer = x => buffer.push(x);

    let subscriber = nextEmitter;
    observable.subscribe(x => subscriber(x));

    pauser.subscribe(value => {
        if (value) {
            subscriber = nextBuffer;
        } else {
            buffer.forEach(nextEmitter);
            buffer = [];
            subscriber = nextEmitter;
        }
    })

    return subj;
};
```

Comment: `observable` and `pauser` are leaking subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this answer, for my use case I turned it into a pipe

```js
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";

export function pausable(pauseToken: Observable<boolean>, startPuased: boolean, lastOnly: boolean) {
    return function <T>(source: Subject<T>): Observable<T> {
        let buffer: T[] = [];
        const nextEmitter = (x: T) => subj.next(x);
        const nextBuffer = (x: any) => buffer.push(x);

        var sourceSubscription: Subscription;
        var pauseSubscription: Subscription;

        var subj = new Subject<T>();

        let subscriber = nextEmitter;
        if (startPuased) {
            subscriber = nextBuffer;
        }
        sourceSubscription = source.subscribe({
            next(value) {
                subscriber(value);
            },
            error(error) {
                subj.error(error);
            },
            complete() {
                subj.complete();
                pauseSubscription?.unsubscribe();
            }
        })

        pauseSubscription = pauseToken.subscribe({
            next(value) {
                if (value) {
                    subscriber = nextBuffer;
                } else {
                    if (lastOnly && buffer.length > 0) {
                        nextEmitter(buffer.pop())
                    } else {
                        buffer.forEach(nextEmitter);
                    }
                    buffer = [];
                    subscriber = nextEmitter;
                }
            },
            complete() {
                sourceSubscription?.unsubscribe();
                pauseSubscription?.unsubscribe();
            }
        });

        return subj;
    }
}
```